# Android i18n Problem

Tags: android, internationalization

I have met an i18n problem in my application. When I change the phone language, some of the strings used by the application is changed, but some not.

Following is what I did:

1. Set the language to Chinese.
2. Launch the application. Current Activity uses Chinese strings.
3. Press HOME key, change the phone language to English.
4. Resume application from history(long press HOME key).

Result: Most strings used by fore Activity are changed to English strings, but there is one string which is the text of a `CheckBox` is still Chinese.

In another Acitivty which also contains an CheckBox, the text of CheckBox also will not be changed after change the phone language.

I have tried many times, just the `CheckBox` text will not be changed. What I can be sure are I do use `<CheckBox android:text="@string/checkbox_text .../>"` in layout xml and the `checkbox_text` string has Chinese version and English version.

Can somebody please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any news on this? I am experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Afaik this should all work but you need to ensure that the application is restarted between changes of locale.